# Alternative method to perform 'r.contour.step'

Tags: python, qgis, grass

I would like to know what algorithm has been used in 'r.contour.step' in QGIS processing Toolbox. What is the method incorporated ?
I was thinking on not making use of QGIS or GRASS packages in python (i.e. "import grass.script as grass","import PyQt4.QtGui","import PyQt4.QtCore").